# Change the "Free Form Signing" Menu options in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

If you do not add any tabs to an envelope then it becomes what's known as a Free-Form signing experience. During free-form signing the recipients decide where to place tabs on the documents as well as the location of those tabs, instead of the sender controlling those aspects.

In this case a menu list occurs on the screen listing multiple options (FirstName, LastName, Date, Signature, etc).

Now the question-

I am looking for one of the following behaviors-
1) Is there any way we can disable/ hide all options (FirstName, LastName, etc) in the above list except for the Signature field. In short I want to see just 'Signature field' in the menu. Is this possible?

2) Considering 'Free form signing' is the default behavior, is there any way to customize this default behavior? 
I am actually signing the document using 'Anchor string' and if the anchor string is not present in the document I need to add a default 'Signature tab' at some default position. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of Free Form Signing as the default. Think of it as the fallback that your senders **should not use.**

Your senders should always add fields to their documents. To help ease the burden, you can use templates, your API program can place the fields on the document, etc.

At a high level, your senders want to get their documents signed by the signers. Making the signers figure out the Free Form Signing experience is a big mistake. Your senders are putting an unnecessary burden on your signers. The only thing that can accomplish is to delay or stop your signers from signing. And that's not in your senders' best interest.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is no way to disable those various tabs during free form signing (FFS), or only display the 'signature tab'

2) If you enable 'document visibility', then FFS is not allowed and the envelope will not be allowed to be created in this case, if you want to consider this approach as a way to prevent FFS.